# Rotation in cylindrical coordinates and exterior derivative

Tags: rotations, cylindrical-coordinates, exterior-derivative

Suppose a 1-form $A$ of $\mathbb{R}^3$ is represented as $A= A_r (r,\theta,z)dr + A_\theta (r,\theta,z)d\theta + A_z(r,\theta,z)dz$ using cylindrical coordinate system $(r,\theta, z)$.

The external derivative of $A$ is
$dA = \Bigl( \dfrac{\partial A_z}{\partial \theta} - \dfrac{\partial A_\theta}{\partial z} \Bigr) d\theta\wedge dz
+\Big( \dfrac{\partial A_r}{\partial z} - \dfrac{\partial A_z}{\partial r} \Big) dz\wedge dr
 + \Big( \dfrac{\partial A_\theta}{\partial r} - \dfrac{\partial A_r}{\partial \theta} \Big) dr\wedge d\theta
$.

$*dA=\dfrac{1}{r} \Bigl( \dfrac{\partial A_z}{\partial \theta} - \dfrac{\partial A_\theta}{\partial z} \Bigr)dr 
+ r \Big( \dfrac{\partial A_r}{\partial z} - \dfrac{\partial A_z}{\partial r} \Big) d\theta 
+\dfrac{1}{r} \Big( \dfrac{\partial A_\theta}{\partial r} - \dfrac{\partial A_r}{\partial \theta} \Big) dz $.

$(*dA)^\sharp = \dfrac{1}{r} \Bigl( \dfrac{\partial A_z}{\partial \theta} - \dfrac{\partial A_\theta}{\partial z} \Bigr) \dfrac{\partial}{\partial r} 
+ \dfrac{1}{r} \Big( \dfrac{\partial A_r}{\partial z} - \dfrac{\partial A_z}{\partial r} \Big) \dfrac{\partial}{\partial \theta}
+\dfrac{1}{r} \Big( \dfrac{\partial A_\theta}{\partial r} - \dfrac{\partial A_r}{\partial \theta} \Big) \dfrac{\partial}{\partial z}  $.

But, for $\textbf{A}:= A_r (r,\theta,z)\dfrac{\partial}{\partial r}
 + A_\theta (r,\theta,z)\dfrac{\partial}{\partial \theta}
 + A_z(r,\theta,z)\dfrac{\partial}{\partial z}$, according to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Del_in_cylindrical_and_spherical_coordinates),　$\nabla \times \textbf{A} \neq (*dA)^\sharp$. I would like to know why.

=====================================
I should have written 1-form $A$ as $A=A_rdr + A_\theta rd\theta + A_zdz$.

Comment: Is $e_\theta$ the dual basis element corresponding to $d\theta$?

Comment: @TedShifrin I apologize for the lack of explanation. $(dr, dθ, dz)$ is the basis of the cotangent space of a point in $ \mathbb{R}^3$. $( \textbf{e}_r, \textbf{e}_\theta, \textbf{e}_z )$ is the basis of cylindrical coordinate system.

Comment: Yes, I know. You say “the basis.” I presume that you’re taking an orthonormal basis with the $\mathbf e$’s. Shouldn’t you have an orthonormal basis with the $1$-forms, too?

Comment: Thanks to your suggestion, my question has been solved. Thank you.

Comment: You’re welcome. Perhaps you should post the answer as an answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formulas in  [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Del_in_cylindrical_and_spherical_coordinates#Del_formula) assume an orthonormal basis
$$
\{\partial_r,\textstyle\frac{1}{r}\partial_\theta,\partial_z\}
$$
(in their notation $\{\hat{\boldsymbol{\rho}},\hat{\boldsymbol{\varphi}},\hat{\boldsymbol{z}}\}$)
w.r.t. the well-known cylindrical metric
$$
g=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\0&r^2&0\\0&0&1 \end{pmatrix}\,.
$$
The dual basis is obviously
$$
\{dr,r\,d\theta,dz\}\,.
$$
OP's ansatz
$$
A=A^r\,dr+A^\theta\,d\theta+A^z\,dz
$$
tells us that the components of $A$ are in the coordinate basis
$\{\partial_r,\partial_\theta,\partial_z\}\,.$ To get this into the
the orthonormal basis we
modify $A^\theta\,,$ that is, we make the ***better ansatz***
\begin{align}
A&=A^r\,dr+A^\theta\,\color{red}{r}\,d\theta+A^z\,dz\,.
\end{align}
Then,
\begin{align}
dA&=(\partial_\theta A^z-r\,\partial_zA^\theta)\,d\theta\wedge dz+
(\partial_zA^r-\partial_rA^z)\,dz\wedge dr+(A^\theta+r\,\partial_rA^\theta-\partial_\theta A^r)\,dr\wedge d\theta\,.
\end{align}
Since  the Hodge dual requires the orthonormal basis lets write this
as
\begin{align}
dA&=\Big(\frac{\partial_\theta A^z}{r}-\partial_zA^\theta\Big)\,r\,d\theta\wedge dz+
(\partial_zA^r-\partial_rA^z)\,dz\wedge dr\\&\quad+\Big(\frac{A^\theta}{r}+\partial_rA^\theta-\frac{\partial_\theta A^r}{r}\Big)\,dr\wedge (r\,d\theta)\,.
\end{align}
Then,
\begin{align}
*dA&=\Big(\frac{\partial_\theta A^z}{r}-\partial_zA^\theta\Big)\,dr+
(\partial_zA^r-\partial_rA^z)\,r\,d\theta+\Big(\frac{A^\theta}{r}+\partial_rA^\theta-\frac{\partial_\theta A^r}{r}\Big)\,dz\,,
\end{align}
and therefore
\begin{align}
(*dA)^\sharp&=\Big(\frac{\partial_\theta A^z}{r}-\partial_zA^\theta\Big)\,\partial_r+
(\partial_zA^r-\partial_rA^z)\,\frac{\partial_\theta}{r}+\Big(\frac{A^\theta}{r}+\partial_rA^\theta-\frac{\partial_\theta A^r}{r}\Big)\,\partial_z\,.
\end{align}
The $\partial_z$-component can obviously be written as
$$
\frac{A^\theta+r\,\partial_rA^\theta-\partial_\theta A^r}{r}\,\partial_z
=
\frac{\partial_r(rA^\theta)-\partial_\theta A^r}{r}\,\partial_z\,.
$$
This shows that $(*dA)^\sharp$ equals the formula for $\nabla\times A$ from
[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Del_in_cylindrical_and_spherical_coordinates#Del_formula).

Comment: Thank you for your response. I appreciate that the cause of my mistake is clearly pointed out.

Comment: Can you formally accept the answer? (The bot will unnecessarily push it back to the active queue if nobody does that.)